# Measure Theory & Integration

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ = {$\omega$$_i$}$^{\infty}_{i=1}$ be a countable set.

Let $\mathscr{A}$ := $\mathscr{P}$($\Omega$) be the power set of $\Omega$

Let $\mu$ be a measure on ($\Omega$, $\mathscr{A}$)

Prove that, for each function $f$: $\Omega$ $\to$ $[0,\infty$), we have:

$\int$$f$ d$\mu$  =  $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$ $f(\omega_i$) $\mu({\omega_i})$

This is an example my lecturer has set for us before next week, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I'm not entirely sure what we're dealing with, is $f$ a simple function?
Because I have seen a few examples that deal with this, but $f$ is a simple function, and it says that:

$\int$$f$ d$\mu$  =  $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$ $a_i$ $\mu({\omega_i})$

Would I be wrong in assuming that $a_i$ are the values of $f(\omega_i$) ?

Could someone help me out? Point me in the direction of some literature, or even just tell me what I'm dealing with

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This works for **any** function $f$. And such an arbitrary function $f$ is a simple function:
$$
f=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(\omega_i)\,1_{\{\omega_i\}}.
$$
As $f$ is positive, $f_n\nearrow f$, where $f_n=\sum_{i=1}^nf(\omega_i)\,1_{\{\omega_i\}}$. Then, by monotone convergence, 
$$
\int f\,d\mu=\int\lim f_n\,d\mu=\lim_n\int f_n\,d\mu=\lim_n\sum_{i=1}^nf(\omega_i)\,\mu(\{\omega_i\})=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(\omega_i)\,\mu(\{\omega_i\})
$$

Comment: An interesting consequence of this is to see that monotone convergence works for sequences but not necessarily for nets: in an uncountable measure space this trick doesn't work (because non-simple functions do exist).